# Simple random walk on $\mathbb{Z}^d$: formal definitions in continuous time.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, expected-value, random-walk

Let $(X_t)_{t\geq0}$ be a **simple symmetric random walk** on $\mathbb{Z}^d$ in **continuous time**.

This means that when the walker $X$ lands on a site $x\in\mathbb{Z}^d$, an $Exp(1)$-clock starts counting time; when this clock rings, the walker jumps to a randomly chosen neighbour $y\in\mathbb{Z}^d$.

Let's suppose that the walk starts at the origin, $X_0=0$. Let $x\in\mathbb{Z}^d$ and $t\geq0$ be a fixed site and instant in time, respectively. Let us consider the quantity

$$
T_x=\int_0^t1_{\{X_s=x\}}ds.
$$

I encountered the above quantity in a paper I am reading. It is supposed to be intended as the (random) amount of time spent by the walker $X$ on the site $x$, up until time $t$. This is quite clear (the integrand equals $1$ whenever $X_s=x$, and $0$ otherwise).

Nevertheless, I have some perplexities regarding the formal *definition* of $T_x$, e.g.:

- is the integral defining $T_x$ supposed to be intended as a Riemann integral?
- the integrand is a random process (i.e. a collection of random variables, indexed by the continuous parameter $s$), and $T_x$ is thus a random variable; is everything well defined? If yes, how? What is the formal theory behind such objects?

I would be grateful to anybody pointing to references for formal definitions of the above mentioned concepts. I am familiar with collections of countably many random variables, not with collections of uncountably many of them, let alone with integrals of such quantities.

Moreover, then paper goes on stating that

$$
\mathbb{P}(T_x>0)=\frac{\mathbb{E}(T_x)}{\mathbb{E}(T_x|T_x>0)},
$$

and regarding it as a triviality. Is it the case? Could anybody help me working out the above equality?

Thank you.

Comment: You have less technical issues to be concerned about if you define $T_x$ through the Lebesgue integral. Anyway, defining the foundational theory of continuous time stochastic processes from scratch is actually quite annoying. The fundamental starting point is the Kolmogorov extension theorem, which basically tells you that it is possible to bootstrap a full continuous time process by specifying all the finite dimensional distributions, provided a rather natural compatibility condition is satisfied.

Comment: As for that equation, that *is* trivial, it is just the total expectation formula combined with the fact that $T_x \geq 0$ by definition. Thus $\mathbb{E}(T_x)=\mathbb{E}(T_x \mid T_x>0) \cdot \mathbb{P}(T_x>0) + \mathbb{E}(T_x \mid T_x=0) \cdot \mathbb{P}(T_x=0)$.